# How do I make this plugin work with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, page-init

I have a scroll bar plugin that only works if I refresh the page, and I'm trying to make it work seamlessly.  I reference it with this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="cubiq-iscroll-bad88fb/src/iscroll.js"></script>
```

The whole plugin (iscroll.js) is wrapped in this:

```js
(function(window, doc){a lot of stuff});
```

Can I somehow replace that function with something like this

```js
$('#transPage, #categorizePage, #IDKPage').live('pageinit', function( ){a lot of stuff});
```

so that it loads without needing to refresh?

Comment: how are you calling the code that works when you refresh?

Comment: I'm not sure what u mean.  I call the code with `<script type="text/javascript" src="cubiq-iscroll-bad88fb/src/iscroll.js"></script>` in the head of every page.

Comment: perhaps you could use `getScript` within `pageinit` instead of putting script tag in head. I'm guessing your scroll script is being overwritten when JQM renders page. Provide link to plugin docs.

Comment: I tried this `$('#transPage, #categorizePage, #IDKPage').live('pageinit', function( ){$.getScript("../cubiq-iscroll-bad88fb/src/iscroll.js")});` but no dice

Answer (score 0):

Don't use iscroll on jQM project.

Use these two plugins instead:

1. [JQM iscrollview](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) - plugin created for purpose of iScroll integration with the jQuery mobile.
2. [Overthrow](http://filamentgroup.github.com/Overthrow/) - another alternative

Combination of jQM and Pure iScroll is not a good one mainly because pure iScroll was not built to work with jQM page logic.